# Getting FullCalendar working with NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, fullcalendar

I would like to get FullCalendar working on NextJS 13. I can get the calendar to show, but I cannot load the CSS.  The official doc says next needs to transpile modules: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/tree/main/next

and elsewhere it suggests using a css-loader - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/initialize-es6

I've tried these approaches, along with a couple of other points mentioned in other SO posts.  Nothing works.

Has anybody actually got this working on v13 yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, First I use `@fullcalendar` v6 version, but hade problem with styles. So in `v6` they move `css styles` from external file to `shadow DOM` and `next js` going through routes somehow removed those styles.

Searching in `github issues` I found few tasks with the same problem: [Styles are not applied correctly for elements using shadow DOM. #7118](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7118), 
[Option to load calendar CSS from an external file instead of injection
#7220](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7220)

So as workaround was downgrade from v6 to v5 using that settings: [How To Use Fullcalendar With Next.js](https://spacebro.io/articles/fullcalendar-nextjs-10-higher).

install v5 libs:

```
npm i @fullcalendar/common@5 @fullcalendar/interaction@5 @fullcalendar/react@5
```

Then install presets:

```
npm i next-transpile-modules @babel/preset-react
```

Then update `nextJs` config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  "@fullcalendar/common",
  "@babel/preset-react",
  "@fullcalendar/common",
  "@fullcalendar/daygrid",
  "@fullcalendar/interaction",
  "@fullcalendar/react",
  "@fullcalendar/timegrid",
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  // your custom config goes here
});
```

Import styles to _app.js (.ts) (in `nextJs` v13.5.6 + `@fullcalendar` v5 it works without adding those styles at all, but I put it here in case if you are using different versions):

```
import "@fullcalendar/common/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";
```

And use package:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

const Calendar = () => {
  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[interactionPlugin]}
      editable
      selectable
    />
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```